# App em Android Studio com banco de dados SQLite Java

Tags: java, android, banco-de-dados, android-studio, sqlite

Estou desenvolvendo um app que tira fotos e salva ela junto com um texto escrito pelo próprio usuário no banco de dados SQL. Por enquanto eu consigo fazer ele tirar a foto e abrir a caixa de texto para o usuário digitar, mas não consigo fazer ele salvar esse texto junto com a imagem no banco de dados, gostaria de saber como eu poderia fazer isso. Esse é meu código por enquanto, dividido em 2 partes:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

public class CameraToDatabase extends Activity {
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
    ImageView imageView1;
    Imagehelper help;


    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera_to_database);
    help = new Imagehelper(this);
    imageView1 = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    Button B = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.camera);
    B.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        help.insert(byteArray);
    }
}

public void getImage(View view) {

    Cursor c = help.getAll();
    if (c.moveToNext())
    {
        byte[] byteArray = c.getBlob(0);
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
        imageView1.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }
    c.close();
}
}
```

---

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;


/**
 * Created by Davi on 02/08/2015.
 */

public class Imagehelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "clothes.db";
    private static final int SCHEMA_VERSION = 3;
public Imagehelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, SCHEMA_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Image(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,imageblob BLOB);");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
}

public void insert(byte[] bytes) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv.put("imageblob", bytes);
    Log.e("inserted", "inserted");
    getWritableDatabase().insert("Image", "imageblob", cv);

}

public Cursor getAll() {
    return (getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT imageblob FROM Image", null));
}
```

}

Comment: você está recebendo algum erro? ou simplesmente não salva? ou salva e você não consegue retornar o registro?

Comment: Nenhum erro, ele salva a imagem que foi tirada, porém, quando o texto é escrito não consigo fazê-lo salvar na tabela do banco de dados.